# Sort django queryset using string field alphabetically

Tags: django, orm, django-queryset

I want to sort users from model with their last names. I am using
`User.objects.filter(is_active=True).order_by('last_name')`
Still there is no luck. Pls suggest some solution.

Comment: can you post your Model

Comment: **But it is the solution : nothing wrong in your statement**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from django.db.models.functions import Lower

User.objects.filter(is_active=True).order_by(Lower('last_name'))
```

If you want to sort alphabetically you have to use the Lower function. Otherwise, all capitalized words will be at the beginning